# Could any one explain me about below error in the R germinationmetrics Package?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to `compute cumulative germination counts` and `Compute germination indices` and `Plot FPHF curves`

My data structure is the following:

```
 concentration temp rep Day01 Day02 Day03 Day04 Day05 Day06 Day07
    1            0.0   10   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    2            0.5   10   1     0     0     0     0     6     6     6
    3            0.3   10   1     0     0     0     0     8     8     8
    4            0.1   10   1     0     0     0     0     6     6     6
    5            0.0   10   2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    6            0.5   10   2     0     0     0     0     9     9     9
    7            0.3   10   2     0     0     0     0     8     8     8
    8            0.1   10   2     0     0     0     0     6     6     6
    9            0.0   10   3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    10           0.5   10   3     0     0     0     0     5     5     5
    11           0.3   10   3     0     0     0     0     8     8     8
    12           0.1   10   3     0     0     0     0     2     2     2
    13           0.0   20   1     0     0     0     0     0     7     7
    14           0.5   20   1     0     0     0     0    17    17    17
    15           0.3   20   1     0     0     0     0    21    21    21
    16           0.1   20   1     0     0     0     0    20    20    20
    17           0.0   20   2     0     0     0     0     0     7    10
    18           0.5   20   2     0     0     0     0    13    13    13
    19           0.3   20   2     0     0     0     0    18    18    18
    20           0.1   20   2     0     0     0     0    22    22    22
    21           0.0   20   3     0     0     0     0     0    14    14
    22           0.5   20   3     0     0     0     0    15    15    15
    23           0.3   20   3     0     0     0     0    15    15    15
    24           0.1   20   3     0     0     0     0    14    14    14
    25           0.0   30   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    26           0.5   30   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    27           0.3   30   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    28           0.1   30   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    29           0.0   30   2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    30           0.5   30   2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    31           0.3   30   2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    32           0.1   30   2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    33           0.0   30   3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    34           0.5   30   3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    35           0.3   30   3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    36           0.1   30   3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
       Day08 Day09 Day10 Day11 Day12 Day13 Day14 Day15 Day16 Day17 Day18
    1      0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    2     18    18    18    18    20    20    20    20    20    20    20
    3     18    18    18    18    20    20    20    20    20    20    20
    4     16    16    16    16    18    18    18    19    19    19    19
    5      0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    6     22    22    22    22    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    7     22    22    22    22    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    8     18    18    18    18    19    19    19    19    19    19    19
    9      0     0     2     2     2     4     4     4     4     4     4
    10    20    20    20    20    21    21    21    21    21    21    21
    11    17    17    17    17    20    20    20    20    20    20    20
    12    22    22    22    22    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    13     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
    14    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    15    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24
    16    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24
    17    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
    18    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25
    19    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    20    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    21    14    14    14    14    14    14    14    14    14    14    14
    22    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23    23
    23    21    21    21    21    21    21    21    21    21    21    21
    24    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20
    25     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    26     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    27     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    28     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    29     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    30     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    31     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    32     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    33     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    34     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    35     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    36     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


     Day19 Total.Seeds
1      1          25
2     20          25
3     20          25
4     19          25
5      1          25
6     23          25
7     23          25
8     19          25
9      4          25
10    21          25
11    20          25
12    23          25
13     7          25
14    23          25
15    24          25
16    24          25
17    10          25
18    25          25
19    23          25
20    23          25
21    14          25
22    23          25
23    21          25
24    20          25
25     0          25
26     0          25
27     0          25
28     0          25
29     0          25
30     0          25
31     0          25
32     0          25
33     0          25
34     0          25
35     0          25
36     0          25
```

I receive the following error:

```
data(gcdata1)

   
Warning message:
        In data(gcdata1) : data set ‘gcdata1’ not found
```

I created the below variable for `counts.per.intervals`

```
counts.per.intervals <- c("Day01", "Day02", "Day03", "Day04", "Day05",
        +                           "Day06", "Day07", "Day08", "Day09", "Day10",
        +                           "Day11", "Day12", "Day13", "Day14", "Day15", "Day16", "Day17", "Day18", "Day19")
```

As the following variable for `indices`

```
indices<-germination.indices(gcdata1, total.seeds.col = "Total.Seeds",
                        counts.intervals.cols = counts.per.intervals,
                        intervals = 1:19, partial = FALSE, max.int = 5)
```

I received the below error:

```
Error in if (nearest[2] == nearest[1]) { :
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: One of your elements in the `nearest` vector is `NA`.

Comment: Difficult to explain without seeing your code or data.